# Laravel sending email to a lot user

Tags: laravel

i'm worked on system that send email to 30K user, i'm implement with queue and work fine in localhost with limited user but on the live doesn't send mail...do you what should i do?

my job that send mail:

```
class NewestInWeekForSubscription implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function handle()
    {

       foreach (User::cursor() as $user) {
            try{
                if ($user->hasTriedLaminorPlus()) {
                    if ($user->email) {
                        Mail::to($user)->queue(new \App\Mail\NewestInWeekForSubscription($user));
                        dump('email sent to ' . $user->email);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (\Exception $e){
                dump('email not send to ' . $user->email);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

my mail structure:

```
class NewestInWeekForSubscription extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

   public function __construct(User $user,) {
    $this->user          = $user;
}
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject(trans('views.email.marketing.title'))
                    ->view('emails.newest-week-for-subscription');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add QUEUE and MAIL relevant config vars from .env file? Also the result of `ps aux| grep artisan` in terminal

Comment: That will never work. Sending emails represents a heavy workload. as @Alex says, you should queue them. And even that is a risk. Your hosting company will complain. I made an AWS account to take care of mass emailing. As this is most probably an admin function, I created a jQuery based loop in the browser itself. This is not a simple task you want to accomplish. Even if it is completely legal. Sending emails is a complex protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better you use the `bcc()` function instead of `foreach`.